# style and j-script doesn't enqueue to plugin not working

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm just starting my first plug-in in wordpress
and im enqueing css and javascript file but nothing apprear on the wp page neither on the admin page

i've tried a lot of code but here is the final one:

```
function register() {
    add_action(' admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue'));
}


function enqueue() {
        //enqueue all our scripts
        wp_enqueue_style('mypluginstyle', 
                   plugins_url('/assests/mystyle.css', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script('mypluginscript', 
                   plugins_url('/assests/myscript.js', __FILE__));
}

if (class_exists('Firstp')) {
    $firstp = new firstp();
    $firstp->register();
}
```

there is no errors but nothing appear
any help please?

Comment: What's the context of register, is it part of the class Firstp or not, please share the full code in your file so we can have a clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

Replace This function

```
function register() {
         add_action(' admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue', 99);
}
```

to

```
function register() {
         add_action(' admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'enqueue' ));
}
```

This will works. Please try.

Another Solution Try to All Code Replace by below code.

```
class Firstp{

    public function __construct(){
                add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'enqueue' ));
            }

    function enqueue() {
            //enqueue all our scripts
            wp_enqueue_style('mypluginstyle', 
                       plugins_url('/assests/mystyle.css', __FILE__));
            wp_enqueue_script('mypluginscript', 
                       plugins_url('/assests/myscript.js', __FILE__));
    }

}
$my_settings_page = new Firstp();
```

Comment: @Abd Hagiz Al laali can you please try  to print in equeue function to show that function will work or not ??

Answer (score 0):

Since the `register` function doesn't seem to be part of any class, you could try:

```
function register() {
         add_action(' admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue', 99);
}


function enqueue() {
        //enqueue all our scripts
        wp_enqueue_style('mypluginstyle', 
                   plugins_url('/assests/mystyle.css', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script('mypluginscript', 
                   plugins_url('/assests/myscript.js', __FILE__));
}

register();
```

Comment: Please share more details.